# adjusting image position using only html and css

Tags: html, css

I need to move the picture to be on the right side of the list items.
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXNmM.png)

```
    <div class="section">
        <div class="row mid-row">
            <div class="col mid-title">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis sapien. Aliquet sodales quam, accumsan etiam tristique laoreet dignissim massa, molestias etiam venenatis vestibulum sollicitudin</h3>
                <ul class="col list-items flex-child">
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</li>
                </ul>
                <img src="../src/cell_phone_img_croped_resized.jpg" alt="" class="col cell-phone-img_small flex-child">
            </div>
            <img src="../src/cell_phone_img_croped_resized.jpg" alt="" class="col cell-phone-img_large">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it's also uploaded here:

https://codepen.io/tom-abarba/pen/eYYeoJe?fbclid=IwAR1R08diZDAnLVCGunrB9AxAlFkMDlJTy7j7__HMPwOp7Njg0GcyKiArAEo

Comment: You have errors in your html: divs in the ul. Correct those first. Also, it's not a good idea to have a media query with `min-width:768px` and another with `max-width:768`, because there will be a screen width at which those will both be valid.

Comment: fixed the code and the CSS